# URLClassLoader getResourceAsStream returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classloader, embedded-resource

I have a custom `ClassLoader` in my project, that loads a class that is dynamically generated from user input at runtime. For building it I generally followed the instructions from [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader) here but instead used a `URLClassLoader` as a parent as the class may change at runtime.

It works fine for loading the class itself, but as soon as it tries to load associated classes it throws a `NullPointerException` at line 4 (`stream.available()`) in the following code, as the returned stream is null.

```
//file is "java\lang\Object.class" when throwing the exception
private byte[] loadClassFileData(String file) throws IOException { 
    InputStream stream = parent.getResourceAsStream(file);
    int size = stream.available();
    byte buff[] = new byte[size];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
    in.readFully(buff);
    return buff;
}
```

Using the default class loader for *`getResourceAsStream()`* doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The success of `getResource..` when using a relative path like `java\lang\Object.class` depends on the package of the calling class. Make it based on the root of the class path by prefixing the path with `/` e.g. `/java\lang\Object.class` but.. also note that path separator in getting resources should always be forward slash, so `/java/lang/Object.class`. BTW .. ***why*** are you trying to load the `java.lang.Object` class? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: BTW: `stream.available()` doesn't necessarily return the complete number of bytes so you might end up returning truncated data.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I tried adding a '/' and replacing the other backslashes, but it sadly didn't fix the problem. The backslashes come from 'replace(".", File.separatorChar)' which I got from said tutorial. And I am not trying to load the Object class myself, but as far as I know, a loaded class will always try to load the classes it needs via the classloader it was loaded by, so it is using the custom one for loading the object class.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Lothar Oh thanks I just got it from the tutorial and was not really aware of what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 onwards if URLClassLoader is returned null it throws NullPointerException.

refer:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8198803